# Check if Admob interstitial is completed

Tags: ios, swift, admob, segue

I'm building my iOS application, and I've added a couple of advertisement to it. But I just found out a problem.

When the AdMob interstitial is running, It won't perform the segue after the advertisement is done.

```
if self.interstitial.isReady
{    
    self.interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "History", sender: self)
}
```

So, once I press the "X" to close the advertisement, it won't perform the segue. it just remains on the same page as before.

How can I fix this? Thanks!

edit

---

So, when I click on a "SAVE" button, this code will be running.

```
if self.interstitial.isReady
{
   self.interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
   self.interstitialDidDismissScreen(self.interstitial) //Calling the dismiss function here                                          
}
```

<

```
//Advertisement will dismiss from the screen
func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial)
{
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "History", sender: self)
}
```

Somehow it still won't perform the segue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to perform the segue when the user presses the x. to do this use this function:

```
func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {

    //Perform your segue
}
```

Comment: So, after checking this out. I just realized I need to add it to "delegate". Now it works perfectly fine, thanks!